# CSS Fade in content and expand outer div smoothly AngularJS App

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have an angularjs app, and I want to add fade in effects to the content upon getting data, and if the data is bigger than the `min-height` of an `outer div` it should slowly and smoothly expand the `outer div`

I made a Fiddle that mimics it getting data, and once done it displays the content.


<kbd>**`JSFiddle Demo`**</kbd>

I tried to do some of the answers from an [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508605/how-can-i-transition-height-0-to-height-auto-using-css) to my problem, but I keep getting confused.

In the demo, when you click `click to add` it has a `$timeout` after the timeout it loads `records` with data and it displays the data in a flash and the outer div `card` expands quickly to aid the inner data.

**HTML Code:**

```
<body ng-app="myapp">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m6" ng-controller="controller1">
      <div class="card fill1">
        <div class="card-content">
          <span class="card-title">{{title}}</span>
          <div id="settings-controller2" parent="tippy" settings></div>
          <button ng-click="add()">
            click to add
          </button>
          <br/>
          <br/>

          <div class="filler">
            <div ng-show="loader" class="preloader-wrapper big active center-align">
              <div class="spinner-layer spinner-blue-only">
                <div class="circle-clipper left">
                  <div class="circle"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="gap-patch">
                  <div class="circle"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="circle-clipper right">
                  <div class="circle"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <table ng-show="display" border="1">
              <tr ng-repeat="x in records">
                <td>{{x.Name}}</td>
                <td>{{x.Country}}</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

*AngularJS:*

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', [])
  .controller('controller1', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.title = "Controller 1";
    $scope.cache = false;
    $scope.records = [];
    $scope.display = false;
    $scope.loader = false;

    $scope.add = function() {
      console.log("adding");
      $scope.display = false;
      $scope.loader = true;
      $timeout(function() {
        $scope.records = [{
          "Name": "Alfreds Futterkiste",
          "Country": "Germany"
        }, {
          "Name": "Berglunds snabbköp",
          "Country": "Sweden"
        }, {
          "Name": "Centro comercial Moctezuma",
          "Country": "Mexico"
        }, {
          "Name": "Ernst Handel",
          "Country": "Austria"
        }, {
          "Name": "Lfds Atrfc",
          "Country": "Austria"
        }]
        $scope.display = true;
        $scope.loader = false;
      }, 1500);

    }
  });
```

Sorry if the question is confusing, I will try to clarify any questions you may have.

Answer (score 0):

I think a way to accomplish this would be to not show your `.filler` element at all on load by having opacity and height set to zero. Set a `transition: all 0.3s ease-out;` property on it too.

After your content is loaded, apply another class to the filler element. In that new class, apply `opacity: 1;` and `max-height: 9999px;` (max-height will not go beyond needed dimensions, but CSS height wont animate using `auto`.

Comment: add and configure example here ng-Animate https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_animation_css2